# Center of polygon using Solr

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Is there a way in Solr to find center of polygon. we have a GIS dataset indexed which has polygon and multipolygon. is there a direct way to find the center of polygon or multi polygon

Comment: Find as in what context? Return the coordinates of the polygon center, or query polygons by their center / offset / distance to center?

Comment: context is to get polygon center point. say, i will query Solr by name = "abc" this record has property which hold polygon boundary i need to get the center point of this polygon.

Comment: any help on this ?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest pre-calculating the polygon center point - there are multiple ways of doing it, and it isn't necessary to do it when the same result is valid for each document.